# Python: Cast time module as string

Tags: python, time

I have a string in a piece of python code which I want to add a time stamp too. However, when I try to cast the timestamp to a string I get the data type, rather than  a string representation of the timestamp.

The code looks like this,

```
timeStamp = "TIME-" + str(time)
print timeStamp

>>> Time-<module 'time' (built-in)>
```

How do you cast a timestamp as a string to allow it to be concatenated with another string?

Comment: `time` is a module. You can't use `str` on it. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @LutzHorn: the module..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You imported just the `time` module and turned *that* into a string; you need to call the [`time.time()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time):

```
timeStamp = "TIME-" + str(time.time())
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You or someone else will use this answer:

```
from datetime import time

timeStamp = "TIME-" + str(time())
print timeStamp
```

`time()` is actually `datetime.time()`

Cheers.